# Why does these 3 lines of code return address-sanitizer error?

Tags: c, address-sanitizer

[image]

```
int* mostVisited(int n, int* rounds, int roundsSize, int* returnSize){
  
    
    returnSize=malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    
     printf("%d", roundsSize);
  
    return returnSize;
}
```

Here you can try the code: https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-203/problems/most-visited-sector-in-a-circular-track/

Edit: Error disappears if i comment the `print` line.

This is from a Leetcode challenge, I understand that I am somehow accessing a memory block that is not allocated, that I access something out of the allocated memory Stack.

The only explanation that I can come up with is that Leetcode's site somehow doesn't allow me to print inside a `int` function.

Error:

```
=================================================================
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6140000001d0 at pc 0x000000404edd bp 0x7ffd3d94c7e0 sp 0x7ffd3d94c7d0
READ of size 4 at 0x6140000001d0 thread T0
    #2 0x7f337c09f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
0x6140000001d0 is located 0 bytes to the right of 400-byte region [0x614000000040,0x6140000001d0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f337d0baf88 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10bf88)
    #3 0x7f337c09f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c287fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c287fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c287fff8000: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c287fff8010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c287fff8020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c287fff8030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c287fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c287fff8050: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c287fff8060: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c287fff8070: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c287fff8080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==32==ABORTING
```

Comment: The error is not in the function you show. Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @bitmask https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-203/problems/most-visited-sector-in-a-circular-track/

Comment: @Robert That's not your code, at least not that we can see without your login.  Post all relevant code here as text so that others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dbush my whole code is in the question statement, those 3 lines

Comment: @Robert That is **not** your whole code, it's only the function that you think has the problem.  You need to give us enough code that others can, without modification, compile and run and see the same results you do.

Comment: @dbush This is probably one of those coding test things where you only fill out the contents of a shell function and the rest of the code that uses the function is pre-written and may be hidden.

Comment: @dbush the way Leetcode works is that you only write a single function that does one thing, you don't have to write`main()` . Take a look at this person https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxf1Ei0iPKA&ab_channel=ProgrammingLivewithLarry he solves the same problem but he is not using C

Answer (score 1):

Your code has issues, but not the ones you think. There can't be an error in the `printf` : you're passed a value for `roundsSize`, you print it, period.

You're passed `returnSize`, which is a pointer. You then assign to the local version of `returnSize`, which doesn't go back to the caller (to do that, you need `**returnSize`). But you then return the new value anyway... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: this is a Leetcode problem, i have to return the pointer once i allocate the right values into it, but first i was trying to see why i kept getting the address sanitizer error, so I kept trying out values that's why i used `print("%d", roundsSize)` and I noticed I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

`returnSize` is probably already pointing to a good memory location readable by the calling function.  Its purpose is to act as another return value so you can inform the calling function the size of the array that you are returning.  Instead, you are re-assigning (the local version of) it to point to the array that you are also returning.

The calling function never sees this change to `returnSize` because the only changes you made to it were localized to the function and didn't modify the data that was stored at the original memory address.  The data at this address is likely garbage as it is expecting your function to give it its value.  If this garbage value happens to be larger than the size of your array, the calling function will likely try to read past the end of the array you allocated.

So the way you should be doing this is probably something along these lines:

```
int* mostVisited(int n, int* rounds, int roundsSize, int* returnSize){
{
    *returnSize = 100; // or however it is that the size of the array should be determined
    int *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret) * *returnSize);

    return ret;
}
```

Of course the rest of the logic for what the function is supposed to do is still up to you to complete.

Comment: /**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
This is written in the problem statement so I don't think I am doing wrong by malloc-ing some memory. Please try this code here https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-203/problems/most-visited-sector-in-a-circular-track/ . It takes less than 5 seconds

Comment: That is referring to your return value.  Not `returnSize`.

Comment: @Robert "it takes less than 5 seconds"... In fact, it takes an account to be created...

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I am believe `returnSize` should be a vector, I will upload in this question the whole problem statement

Comment: Your return value should be an array.  `returnSize` will be the size of the array you return.  It is the only way for the calling function to know the size of the array.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons if i try to modify or to print out `returnSize` same error occurs, the 'address sanitizer' one that is stated in the question's statement

Comment: Are you still pointing `returnSize` to your `malloc`'d data?  Because don't do that.